# MathCad Variable Undefined (even though I just defined it)

Tags: math-software

Hoping to run into some mathcadders:

I have a worksheet which includes the following except (and error)

[image: Mathcad fail]

Any help?

Comment: To be honest, you are likely to find more timely help if you asked on the support forum (assuming it exists) of MathCad. I'm not sure how likely you are to find an answer here, but good luck.

Comment: Is this on topic for our site?  (I'm not saying it isn't.  I'm just asking.)

Comment: @Pete: according to the  FAQ, it is. Last bullet point of questions welcomed is "softwares that mathematicians use".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathcad "reads" down and right and you have defined the equation above the variable definition. If you drag the equation down it will work.

If you are going to be using Mathcad regularly, you might be interested in joining the Mathcad User Community:

http://communities.ptc.com/index.jspa

Chris Hartmann, Academic Program Manager, Mathcad

Comment: welcome to Math.SE, and thanks for providing the solution! I hope you will continue to visit every now and then as I'm sure more Mathcad problems will pop up as the site gets more popular.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of subscripts in Mathcad:

the text subscript (.) and the mathematical subscript ([)

you must use C.t when you define the variable